# WCF Service - does not return related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, debugging

Basically, I have a WCF service that connects a DB via Entity Framework.

Now, I know about eager loading VS. lazy loading and within the service I indeed get all the desired related entities from the DB. The problem occurs when I return to the view-model which has called the service and there the related entities are set to null for some weird reason.

Please, let me demonstrate:
Here is the view model that calls the service:

[image]

Now, here is the service method "GetAllWorkers()" which has been invoked:

[image]

Now, when I'm in debug mode, here is what is returned within the service method:
[image]

As you can see, the related tasks of the worker are returned as I wanted.
So, the eager loading has been done successfully.

The problem occured when I return to the view-Model: (using F11 - step into)

[image]

Ok, how is it possible, the service method returned the related entities, but when I'm back at the client (at the view model), the related tasks that were returned are now set to null.

I use Channel Factory without adding service reference if that matters.

Thanks! And if you need me to provide you with some additional code, please let me know!

Comment: could you show me GetAllWorkers method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I dont know if I understood you well, but for be siure please try use:

```
List<Worker> worker = new List<Worker>(proxy.GetAllWorkers());
```

OR

If workertasks field is reference type variable then it could happen, maybe you deliver reference to scope where you have not acccess to

EDIT:
and are the Worker class DataContract?

Comment: I will try this, and if it does not work, I'll paste all the related code. And yes, worker is a Data Contract.

Comment: OMG--> I've put [Data Member] Attributes on all of the Worker Class properties except the WorkerTasks. 
Thanks, Taumantis, you were right, I didn't have access to that field.
Now, everything works fine.